# Thresholding an image with a low and high threshold in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to threshold an image with a low and high threshold. I already performed thresholding on a hue channel of a HSV picture, but I want to threshold it between two numbers.
Is there a way to do two thresholding operations in one?

```
rgb = io.imread("image.jpg")
hsv = rgb2hsv(rgb)
hue = hsv[:, :, 0] > 0.5
```

Comment: Which modules are you using? The `io` module doesn't provide a function called `imread`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny io is imported from skimage

Comment: I found a method in numpy: `AB = np.logical_and(A, B)` and read about it in context of image processing. It occurs that it is used to threshold between numbers. But I still don't know how to use it.

Comment: This does exactly as you ask... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514956/2836621

Comment: Thank you for your help, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/64514956/2836621) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean- indexing

```
hsv[(hsv[:,:,0] > upper_thresh) | (hsv[:,:,0] < lower_thresh)] = value
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. And also I think there should be a logical **and** like I commented on the question `AB = np.logical_and(A, B)`