# Drawing rectangles given X and Y coords around specific brightness points- python

Tags: python, image, opencv, astronomy

I began scripting code to aid me in my research in the correlation between globular clusters and galaxy types. So, my code was able to find all possible globular clusters in distance galaxy and return the X and Y coords. Now, I need to figure out how to actually be able to draw little boxes around the X and Y coords, so I can see the distribution visually. Code below:

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt
imag = Image.open("Centaurus_A-DeNoiseAI-denoise.jpg")
imag = imag.convert ('RGB')
x=[]
y=[]
for i in range(3008):
    X,Y = i,i
    (R,G,B) = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
    brightness = sum([R,G,B])/3
    if(94<brightness<124):
        print(X,Y)
        x.append(X)
        y.append(Y)
```

Comment: cv2.rectangle(imag, x-10, x+10, (You're color in BGR), (thickness))

Comment: This throws the error of: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img', what is the meaning of this? How do I bypass it?

Comment: Ah I just saw you initialized your image with PIL and I'm getting you to draw with opencv. Let me just write the answer.

Comment: Your code appears to only look at pixels on the diagonal, where X==Y, is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes I fixed that I put a for loop in a for loop so that it can go row by row

Comment: You really shouldn't process images with `for` loops in Python - it is very inefficient, error-prone and slow. Try to get in the habit of using `Numpy` or **OpenCV**. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514956/2836621 You can get the mean of RGB channels with `mean = np.mean(im, axis=2)`. You can threshold how I show in the linked answer. You can get the X,Y coordinates with `np.where()`. Your whole code can be done around 100x faster and more simply in 3-4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your already existing code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#Your code from before here

with imag as im:
    delta = 5
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        draw.rectangle([x[i-delta],y[i-delta],x[i-delta],y[i-delta]], fill=(255,0,0))

    im.save("your_image","PNG")
```

Adjust delta accordingly to how much padding you want on that rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, the code works but I think I have a system error, a library isn't installed maybe? But the code throws this error: AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Draw'

Comment: Sorry, typo on my end.

Comment: No, problem I fixed it, one last thing. So it runs and then it throws the final error of,  TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list but I created a list of x and y in my code to hold all x and y values, what am I missing? And sorry for bugging you, I just need this for my project :)

Comment: Hey, is there any way to change the color of the boxes to red?

Comment: Fixed a mistake. Color can be changed by `draw.rectangle([x[i]-delta,y[i]-delta,x[i]-delta,x[y]-delta], fill=rgb(255,0,0)`

Comment: No problem, Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Actually I think you meant: draw.rectangle([x[i-delta],y[i-delta],x[i-delta],y[i-delta]], fill=(255,0,0))